# Adding custom fields to featured products in Big Commerce

Tags: e-commerce, product, bigcommerce

How can I add custom fields to featured products in Big Commerce? I'm using the 'LifeStyle' theme. I've added the custom fields in the product page (in the admin) but in the Stencil, e.g. on the home page, do not get the option to add it: [image: stencil view of home page])

I also cannot locate any files that would have any of the markup in. Only in `home.html` I can see `{{{region name="home_below_new_products"}}}` which I know to be the code that displays this section (when viewing the home page with dev tools to see the markup). But there doesn't seem to be any accessible files to edit any of this.

__

Also just to add that in trying to create a custom widget (via the APIs - as per suggestions given below), I'm still not yet able to output this to the user. My widget template JSON looks like this:

```
{
   ...,
   "storefront_api_query": "query ProductSet($productIds: [Int!], $activeCurrencyCode: currencyCode!) {\n  site {\n    settings {\n      storeName\n      tax {\n        plp\n      }\n    }\n    currency(currencyCode: $activeCurrencyCode) {\n      display {\n        symbol\n        symbolPlacement\n        decimalToken\n        decimalPlaces\n        thousandsToken\n      }\n    }\n    products(entityIds: $productIds) {\n      edges {\n        node {\n          brand {\n            name\n          }\n          name\n          entityId\n          addToCartUrl\n          addToWishlistUrl\n          path\n          sku\n          priceWithTax: prices(includeTax: true, currencyCode: $activeCurrencyCode)  {\n            price {\n              currencyCode\n              value\n            }\n          }\n          priceWithoutTax: prices(includeTax: false, currencyCode: $activeCurrencyCode)  {\n            price {\n              currencyCode\n              value\n            }\n          }\n          reviewSummary {\n            summationOfRatings\n            numberOfReviews\n          }\n          defaultImage {\n            url80wide: url(width: 80)\n            url160wide: url(width: 160)\n            url320wide: url(width: 320)\n            url640wide: url(width: 640)\n            url960wide: url(width: 960)\n            url1280wide: url(width: 1280)\n            url1920wide: url(width: 1920)\n          }\n        customFields {\n        edges {\n        node {\n          name\n          value}\n}\n}\n}\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n",
   "template": "<div id=\"sd-product-set-{{_.id}}\"></div>\n\n{{#each products as |product|}}\n  {{#each ../_.data.site.products.edges as |productResource|}}\n    {{#if productResource.node.entityId \"==\" product.productId}}\n      <script type=\"application/ld+json\">\n        {\n          \"@context\": \"https://schema.org/\",\n          \"@type\": \"Product\",\n          \"name\": \"{{productResource.node.name}}\",\n          \"image\": \"{{productResource.node.defaultImage.url}}\",\n          \"description\": \"{{product.productDescription}}\",\n          \"sku\": \"{{productResource.node.sku}}\",\n          \"potency\": \"{{#each productResource.node.customFields.edges}}{{#if node.name \"==\" \"potency\"}}{{ node.value }}{{/if}}{{/each}}\",\n          \"aggregateRating\": {\n            \"@type\": \"AggregateRating\",\n            {{#if productResource.node.reviewSummary.summationOfRatings \"==\" 0}}\n            \"ratingValue\": \"0\",\n            {{else}}\n            \"ratingValue\": \"{{divide productResource.node.reviewSummary.summationOfRatings productResource.node.reviewSummary.numberOfReviews}}\",\n            {{/if}}\n            \"reviewCount\": \"{{productResource.node.reviewSummary.numberOfReviews}}\"\n          },\n          \"offers\": {\n            \"@type\": \"Offer\",\n            \"priceCurrency\": \"{{productResource.node.prices.price.currencyCode}}\",\n            \"price\": \"{{productResource.node.prices.price.value}}\",\n            \"seller\": {\n              \"@type\": \"Organization\",\n              \"name\": \"{{../../../_.data.site.settings.storeName}}\"\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      </script>\n    {{/if}}\n  {{/each}}\n{{/each}}\n\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n  (function() {\n    var widgetConfiguration = {{{json .}}};\n    var dataIsNotPresent = typeof widgetConfiguration._.data === 'undefined' || Object.keys(widgetConfiguration._.data || {}).length === 0;\n    var storefrontApiQueryData = widgetConfiguration._.queryData;\n\n    function executeStorefrontApiQuery(queryData, callback) {\n      // Fetch data from the GraphQL Storefront API\n      var storefrontApiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE compatible\n      storefrontApiRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {\n        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {\n          callback(JSON.parse(this.response).data);\n        }\n      };\n\n      storefrontApiRequest.open('POST', `/graphql`, true);\n      storefrontApiRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${queryData.storefrontApiToken}`);\n      storefrontApiRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');\n      storefrontApiRequest.send(JSON.stringify({ query: queryData.storefrontApiQuery, variables: JSON.parse(queryData.storefrontApiQueryParamsJson) }));\n    }\n\n    function loadScript(src, onload) {\n        const scriptTag = document.createElement('script');\n        scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';\n        scriptTag.defer = true;\n        scriptTag.src = src;\n        if (onload) {\n            scriptTag.onload = onload;\n        }\n        document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);\n    }\n\n    function executeWidget(configuration, storefrontApiData) {\n      if (storefrontApiData) {\n        configuration._.data = storefrontApiData;\n      }\n      {{#if _.context.isEditorMode '===' true}}\n        var scriptPath = (build) => `https://microapps.bigcommerce.com/product-set-widget/b5bcd08d0f4673db814c9ad9a35c90873a9f2f58/${build}-bundle.js`;\n        if (window.BigCommerce\n                && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet\n                && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet === 'function'\n                && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSetPageBuilderComm\n                && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSetPageBuilderComm === 'function') {\n            const productSet = window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet(configuration);\n            window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSetPageBuilderComm(productSet);\n        } else {\n            loadScript(scriptPath('storefront'), () => {\n                const productSet = window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet(configuration);\n                loadScript(scriptPath('pageBuilder'), () => {\n                    window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSetPageBuilderComm(productSet);\n                });\n            });\n        }\n      {{else}}\n        var storefrontScriptPath = \"https://microapps.bigcommerce.com/product-set-widget/b5bcd08d0f4673db814c9ad9a35c90873a9f2f58/storefront-bundle.js\";\n        if (window.BigCommerce && window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet && typeof window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet === 'function') {\n            window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet(configuration).setup();\n        } else {\n            loadScript(storefrontScriptPath, () => window.BigCommerce.initializeProductSet(configuration).setup());\n        }\n      {{/if}}\n    }\n\n    if (dataIsNotPresent && storefrontApiQueryData) {\n      executeStorefrontApiQuery(storefrontApiQueryData, function(storefrontApiData) { executeWidget(widgetConfiguration, storefrontApiData) });\n    } else {\n      executeWidget(widgetConfiguration);\n    }\n  })();\n</script>\n",
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom_fields are present on the home, category, brand and product pages if they are the standard Stencil based pages.

When present, a product object will contain a custom_fields property, which is an array of {id, name, value} objects.

Where you find them varies.

The home page has product arrays in:

products.featured
products.new
products.top_sellers

For the category pages, they are in category.products.

For brand pages, it's brand.products.

And for product pages, it's just the one object in product.

More on the Stencil objects:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/stencil/themes/context/object-reference/schemas

Comment: thanks. As mentioned the only code referring to the section with my products (on the home page, i.e. `home.html`) is `{{{region name="home_below_new_products"}}}` So I'm thinking that I can't get at the code itself. Otherwise I would need to create a custom product list, i.e. code it myself. That's if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Above that region line you should see a line including components/products/new. That in turn includes components/products/carousel, which in turn loops through all the products and uses components/products/card. 

The card component displays a single product in a list, like the category page. There, you can add your custom_fields. The card is called in the context of a single product: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/stencil/themes/context/object-reference/schemas#product

Comment: It's a good effort but I can't see any of the markup in those files in the page (in dev tools) so I'm not sure that that is where it is getting generated so I'm quite confused (still)

Comment: Do you have a components/products/card.html file? That is the most relevant one if your theme follows the standard pattern. It defines what each product looks like in a list.

Comment: Yes - I've got that file but it just doesn't appear to be making any difference to the rendering on screen. So still baffled!

Comment: Maybe your theme developer changed how it works. I think you need to talk to them.

Comment: Thank-you Tony! Although it hasn't quite worked out for me, I'm sure there are those out there that will find your efforts worthwhile.

Comment: I think @Matt Coy is on the right track with the wedget. I didn't check the screenshot, which confirms that.

Comment: I'm investigating this currently amongst other things so I'll report back

Answer (score 0):

That is a Page builder widget. It is functionally separate from the Stencil context. The default Page Builder widgets are not very flexible. That is the default Product Set Page Builder widget, and it appears there is no way to access the custom fields on it.

If you want to get custom fields on a Page Builder widget, you will need to create a custom widget template that calls for the custom_fields in the GraphQL request.

Here is the API reference for creating custom Page Builder Widget Templates: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/rest-content/widgets/widget-template#create-a-widget-template

There may also be an app you can install that adds custom widgets with more product support. Check https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/categories/?query=widgets

Comment: Thank-you. That might possibly be something but there seems to be a lot of learning there and I haven't found any of the fragmented documentation to be comprehensive. I would be wanting to create a row of products (on mobile swipe-able) like we have for `home_below_new_products` in the storefront.. but of course with my custom field available. Ideally there would be an example that I could play around with to ensure that I can access & render the data as desired but I can see that I would first have to create one. Not even sure how I would call it in the file

Comment: I can't find any example of adding a custom field to a new widget template. Big Commerce really know how to overcomplicate

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/storefront/graphql/examples/products#get-product-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks Matt - very useful. I'm just struggling knowing how to output on the page for the user, i.e. amongst the `<div data-test-id="product-set-widget-brand" class="css-1wn6xct">..</div>` code

Comment: You can write queries in JavaScript and append the values to the cards. Or if you make the custom widget, you can adjust the GQL context to include the custom fields and spit them out directly!

Comment: I created a new widget template adjusting the 'storefront_api_query' by adding `customFields { edges { node { name value }}}` which outputs my custom fields (with the [Storefront Playground](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-storefront/playground)) but I just don't know how to have this output to the user.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? An example would be really useful

Comment: You should be able to call that data within the widget that uses it:
{{#each _.data.site.products.edges}}
    {{#each node.customFields.edges}}
        {{node.name}}: {{node.value}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}

Comment: Still struggling here - I've added details of the ***widget template*** to the bottom of my original post if there's any more pointers you can give. Thanks!

Comment: This is invalid: {{#each products as |product|}}\n  {{#each ../_.data.site.products.edges as |productResource|}}

You should only be using a single each loop: {{#each _.data.site.products.edges}}

Comment: But that's what I lifted from the regular 'Product set' widget template. I thought it best to do this and then just add the 'customFields' part in there. It's messy though and very unclear as to why structured data is in there, etc.

Comment: I would say try setting up the query to grab all data you need, and then just use the single _.data.site... loop

Comment: I've done all this Matt with zero success. My issue is that the logical approach would be to take the existing template in the native 'Product Set' widget and customise this but it doesn't appear to have any HTML Markup that is outputted to the user, e.g. where is the image DOM element, etc, etc? You say that this is generated via JavaScript but where is the documentation to facilitate the customisation of this? Unless you've done this then I'm going to have to assume that it's not possible. Big Commerce is a big confusion